# How do you create a link to a modal dialog?

Tags: modal-dialogs

The following code does not work:

```
<div class="topics"><a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/topics-listing">All Topics</a></div>
```

Drupal 8.6.5. Bootstrap subtheme. Chrome console log shows no errors. Rather than a modal, the referenced page opens.

So, how do you create a link to a modal dialog in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4):

This html looks ok, but did you include the `core/drupal.dialog.ajax` js library that attach event to your link ?

In twig :

```
{{ attach_library('core/drupal.dialog.ajax') }}
```

In PHP, it looks like this :

```
$renderArray = [
            '#title' => t('All Topics'),
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#url' => Url::fromRoute('XXX'),
            '#attributes' => [
                'class' => ['use-ajax'],
                'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
            ],
            '#attached' => [
                'library' => ['core/drupal.dialog.ajax'],
            ],
];
```

Comment: Can you suggest which twig file and where in that file to place the attach_library, please? Thanks, Oulalahakabu

Comment: Activate `debug:true` from `twig.config` in `services.yml`, then you can explore html produced by drupal 8 with your browser and see which twig files are used. You can attach this library anywhere it is usefull.
Note I'm not sure using attach_library is the best practice,